# How to customize template in django-oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

i want to customize django-oscar template according to my requirement , when i modified the checkout page, i had been encoutred with this error :

```
 TemplateSyntaxError at /checkout/thank-you/
 Invalid block tag on line 132: 'oscar_thumbnail', expected 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

this my settings.py :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
             OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR

             ]
    ,
    # 'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
            'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
            'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
            'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
            'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',

        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

how i can register the templatetag into my custom template in django-oscar?

Comment: Please show us the template that you have modified - presumably you have forgotten to load the template tags that the original template uses.

Comment: actually in every html template which uses the load template tags this error occurred , such as {% load thumbnail %} in checkout template , it cant resolve the path after copying it into the template folder , how i can register the template tags after copying ? thanks